# How to display all fractions in web app?

Tags: html, mathjax, fractions

I want to design a simple math app to train fractions. 
I wonder how to display all fractions in all the latest browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE).

Wikipedia embeds them as png, such as:

[image]

But this seems very impracticle for a dynamic web app where I want to generate random fractions that pupil shall work with.

Maybe `Mathjax` could help?

As an example, I want to display `8/5 x 7/4 = ?`.

Comment: You may look at this: http://mathquill.com/

Comment: @Kangkan: That looks great! It seems a lot simpler than Mathjax...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a really simple way with css. In case you want to display fractions only this works great. For more complex arithmetic formulas this solution is probably to complicated.

**Preview**

[Fraction Example Preview http://imageshack.com/a/img824/218/c6y7.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img824/218/c6y7.png)

[CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/ph3nx/pen/Izjct)

**HTML**

```
<div class="fraction">
  <span class="top">8</span>
  <span class="bottom">5</span>
</div>

<div class="fraction">
  <span class="operator">*</span>
</div>

<div class="fraction">
  <span class="top">7</span>
  <span class="bottom">4</span>
</div>

<div class="fraction">
  <span class="operator">= &nbsp; ?</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fraction, .top, .bottom {
    padding: 0 5px;    
}

.fraction {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;    
}

.bottom{
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    display: block;
}

.operator {
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```